# Real numbers and rational number

Tags: real-analysis

I know I am getting somewhere wrong but my question is how rational numbers are real numbers(Q is subset of R) .Rational numbers don't have least upperbound property and lub property is necessary condition for being real numbers

Comment: Every not-empty subset of $\mathbb R$ has a lub in $\mathbb R$ while **not** every not-empty subset of $\mathbb Q$ has a lub in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: The property regards the set of reals (rationals) and not the idividual real (rational) number.

Comment: Yes, but all of rational numbers could be written as least upper bound of a non empty real subset:$\forall q\in\mathbb{Q}$ $ q=sup\{p\in \mathbb{R}\mid p<q\}$

Comment: The set $(0,1)$ does not satisfy the least upper bound property. So is it not a subset of the reals?

Comment: $\mathbb Q$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$ but it is not a *closed* subset, so $\mathbb Q$ has limit points in $\mathbb R \setminus Q$. Thus the supremum of a bounded subset of $\mathbb Q$ may be in $\mathbb R \setminus Q$. Any *closed* subset of $\mathbb R$ will have the least upper bound property.

Answer (score 4):

A bounded subset of the rational numbers has a least upper bound in the real numbers, but not necessarily in the rational numbers.

Many subsets of the real numbers do not have the least upper bound property (within themselves).  For instance, the irrational numbers do not have the least upper bound property.  That is, there are bounded sets of irrational numbers that do not have a least upper bound in the irrationals.  Of course they still have a least upper bound in the reals (but that least upper bound would be rational).

Answer (score 1):

When constructing ${\mathbb R}$ from ${\mathbb Q}$ using Dedekind cuts, Cauchy sequences, or some other method, you make sure that the new system, as complicated as it appears at the start, contains as subset a built in copy $\hat{\mathbb Q}$  which is "computation wise" isomorphic to the ${\mathbb Q}$ you had at the beginning. This has nothing to do with inf and sup.